# Why is it true that "$\sum_{k,l\geq1}a_{kl}=\sum_{m\geq1}\sum_{k+l=m}a_{kl}$"?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Why is it true that "$\sum_{k,l\geq1}a_{kl}=\sum_{m\geq1}\sum_{k+l=m}a_{kl}$"? I encounter this identity quite often, but I don't find it very intuitive. Can someone elaborate on this? Also, is convergence of both sides equivalent? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should write $m\geq2$ in the outer sum of the RHS.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I see your point. But it doesn't really change the outcome, does it?

Comment: What is your definition of $\sum_{k,l\geq1}a_{kl}$?

Comment: Try searching for  anti diagonal sums images. Also easy to find instances where convergence is **not** equivalent.

Comment: @Somos makes a really good point: the series $\sum_{k,l\geq 1} a_{kl}$ is unambiguously defined only if the double sequence $\{a_{kl}\}_{k,l\geq 1}$ is absolutely summable (or if all terms are nonnegative), for otherwise you have to specify the order of summation! On the other hand, the expression $\sum_{m \geq 1} \sum_{k+l=m} a_{kl}$ is unambiguous, so it is possible for this series to converge only conditionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{k, l \ge 1} a_{kl}$ is summing the elements in a $K \times L$ matrix one by one, assuming $1 \le k \le K$ and $1 \le l \le L$.

$\sum_{k\ge 1} \sum_{l \ge 1} a_{kl}$ is summing **by rows** - ie sum all the elements in rows $k=1, k=2, k=3, .. k=K$ in turn, then add all $K$ row-sums together.

$\sum_{l\ge 1} \sum_{k \ge 1} a_{kl}$ is summing **by columns**.

$\sum_{m \ge 1} \sum_{k+l=m} a_{kl}$ is summing the same elements **by anti-diagonals**. Each of the diagonals is defined by $m$ and the terms in each diagonal are summed before moving to the next diagonal.

Whichever order you add the elements, the sum is always the same.

[image]

Comment: Thank for the visuals! I think I understand now! By the way, do you mean "$\infty\times\infty$-matrix"?

Comment: Good point. Yes if indices $k, l$ have no upper limit then that is what I mean.